# Writeable Nested Serializers with PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: serialization, nested, django-rest-framework

I'm having a problem creating (nested) serializers for the following models:

```py
class Chapter(Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    description = TextField(blank=True)

class Section(Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    description = TextField(blank=True)
    chapter = ForeignKey(Chapter, related_name='sections', on_delete=CASCADE)
```

Here is the serializer for the Chapter model with the create method:

```py
class ChapterSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    uuid = UUIDField(read_only=False)
    sections = SectionSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = ('uuid', 'description', 'sections')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        sections = validated_data.pop('sections', [])
        chapter = Chapter.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for section in sections:
            section.update({'chapter': chapter})
            section = Section.objects.create(**section)

        return chapter
```

And here are two slightly different variants of the Section serializer:

```py
class SectionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        uuid = UUIDField(read_only=False)
        chapter = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=true)

        class Meta:
            model = Section
            fields = ('uuid', 'description', 'chapter')

class SectionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        uuid = UUIDField(read_only=False)
        chapter = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Chapter.objects.all())

        class Meta:
            model = Section
            fields = ('uuid', 'description', 'chapter')
```

Now if I try to create a new Chapter with nested Sections and the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` in the Section serializer has the `queryset` parameter set, I get the following error:

```py
'sections': [{'chapter': ['Invalid pk "x" - object does not exist.']}]
```

If I use the variant with the `read_only=true` parameter, creating a new Chapter with nested Sections works, but now I can no longer create a new Section (Chapter field is set to an existing Chapter UUID) because the chapter field is removed while validating the input data.

```py
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "chapter_id" violates not-null constraint
```

I think I could solve this by duplicating the `SectionSerializer`, but this seems to be a very crude solution ...

Anyone knowing of an better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, answering my own question:

I finally found a way to get a "nestable" and a "writeable" version of the `SectionSerializer` without code duplication:

```py
class NestedSectionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    uuid = UUIDField(read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Section
        exclude = ('chapter', )

class SectionSerializer(NestedSectionSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='section-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Section
        fields = '__all__'

class ChapterSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='chapter-detail')
    uuid = UUIDField(read_only=False)
    sections = NestedSectionSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        sections = validated_data.pop('sections', [])
        chapter = Chapter.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for section in sections:
            section.update({'chapter': chapter})
            section = Section.objects.create(**section)

        return chapter
```

The key here ist to explicitly exclude the reverence to `chapter` in the "nested" serializer but add it again in the "writeable" serializer. This even scales to deeply nested structures!

And by using inheritance I can avoid most code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled my hair about this very same question.

The answer is actually in the DRF documentation: you need to explicitely define the queryset argument for the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` if you want them to be writable.

In your case, only the second variant of `SectionSerializer` is necessary.